# Why does the second day ruin the count, and the third day not?

Tags: maseches-zavim

*Zavim*, chapter 1, *mishna* 2, in my own, free translation, following the consensus of major commentators:

> Suppose someone has a seminal emission on the third day of his count of seven clean days after *zov*. *Bes Shamay* say that that cancels the two days he's counted, so he must begin the seven days anew. But *bes Hilel* say that it only ruins the day itself, so he must count five clean days thereafter. Rabbi *Yishmael* says that, even according to *bes Hilel*, if the emission was on the **second** day, then the first day is canceled, and he must begin the seven days anew.

Why the difference between the second and third day (according to Rabbi *Yishmael*'s interpretation of *bes Hilel*)?